# Powershell: Connection problem due to TLS

Tags: powershell, qliksense

I'm using a module for PS called  Qlik-Cli,

This is the code to connect and start a task,

```
>     [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls12"
>     $logpath = "E:\Tools\Scripts\log.txt"
>     Import-Module -Name Qlik-Cli
>     $cert =  gci cert:localmachine\my | where { $_.Thumbprint -eq '1fcad2353817a88b785b11fd543d8c3507fc8bf3'}
>     Connect-Qlik -Computername server1 -Certificate $cert -Username ad\qsadmin
>     Start-QlikTask -id df9dfa2f-32ca-4db4-bdce-15ad923fd59g
```

But I'm having isssues, Invoke-RestMethod : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

QlikSense uses 1.2, therefore I added [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls12".
I tried with other versions.

I been googeling like crazy and can't find much more.
For nPrint, [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls12" solved it with the CLI-module.

Could this be realted to the certificate in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved. The module uses a Certificate QLikSense creates called Qlik Client.

You have to use this with module and not the normal certificate you use with Qlik Sense.

Answer (score 2):

Setting your script to use TLS1.2 does require your server to also support it. Here's some additional troubleshooting to try:

```
# check your client certificate (make sure it's not expired or something):
$cert = gci cert:localmachine\my | where thumbprint -eq '1fcad2353817a88b785b11fd543d8c3507fc8bf3'
# Use -AllowUntrustedRoot if the cert doesn't have a valid revocation list to check
Test-Certificate $cert -AllowUntrustedRoot

# Check the protocols offered by the server include TLS 1.2 - I use nmap (external tool) 
./nmap.exe --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 server1

443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers etc...

# Try and connect manually with the command that's failing:
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://Server1/path/to/api" -Certificate $cert
```

Since it's a rest method, you can also just try and connect in your browser and see if the certificate on the server side looks acceptable.

If your computer doesn't trust the server certificate, you can bypass this check (not recommended). This requires at least powershell v6, and you would have to edit the qlik-cli module.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -SkipCertificateCheck -Certificate $cert
```

Comment: Two comments:
1. It uses TLS 1.2, it's QlikSense by Qlik it has a built in testserver.
2. It's only a FQDN using a *. cert, not the best way of doing it, but a customer decided to have it that way. I created a testserver with QlikSense today just to see and did not have theese issues. Therefore I suspect the cert. I will check when I am back in the office tomorrow and update the case with more info.

Comment: So I looked more at this, tls is open and it's a valid certificate for the dns. It seems you get the problem only when you add -cert, if you don't use that but -trustallcerts it will work. 

Problem here is that I need to use -username, which forces me to use -cert. Everything looks right, so I don't know if there is any network policy or such on the server. Gonna have a chat with the companys it-department about that.

Comment: @Gatewarden I'm not familiar with qlik, but it might be easier to try the `Invoke-RestMethod` command within the module and see if it works. For example, the command you use to set `Tls12` only applies to that session - if qlik starts another session or does remote stuff, your setting may not even be applying.